# All the primes between two parsed user numbers

Tags: java, numbers, primes

I have a question about a problem. I'm a beginner at this so I appreciate your help!
The code should ask for two user input numbers, and will print out in the console all the prime numbers between these two.
Here is the code I got until now: (It's not checking the numbers between these two, only printing out the one number if it's a prime. )

```
package questionsAndAnswers;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Number {
    static boolean primes;
    public static boolean number( ) {
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader System.in));
                String num1 = br.readLine();
                String num2 = br.readLine();

                int number1 = Integer.parseInt(num1);
                int number2 = Integer.parseInt(num2);

                for (int j = number1; j < number2; j++) {
                    if ( (j % 2) == 0 ) return true;
                    for (int k = 3; (k*k) <= j; k+=2) {
                        if(j % k == 0) {
                            return false;
                        }
                        System.out.println("All the primes b/n number " + number1 + " and number" + number2 + "  are :" + j );
                        return true;
                    }
                    System.out.println(primes);
                    // br.close();
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return primes;
    }
}
```

...and in the main class :

```
public class TwoWholeNumbers {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Enter two integer numbers to see what is the multitude b/w them: ");
        Number.number();

    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question? Finish my code? That's not how SO works. You should have a concrete problem.

Comment: My question is what is missing/wrong in my code , to do what I want it? (print out every prime b/n two numbers )... ( as i said I'm a beginner, sorry if the question is not so concrete )

Comment: When you post code make sure it actually compiles. The code you posted was missing opening brackets and the indentation was all over the place. If you want people to read your code, make sure it is readable. Use 4 spaces (not tabs) to indent lines and make sure the indents match.

Comment: Will do for next time. Thank You for Your remarks! What am I doing wrong btw ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have copy pasted code from some place. Issue is you are breaking after first value.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Number {
    static boolean primes;

    public static boolean number() {
        try {     
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {

                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                            System.in));
                String num1 = br.readLine();
                String num2 = br.readLine();

                int number1 = Integer.parseInt(num1);
                int number2 = Integer.parseInt(num2);

                for (int j = number1; j < number2; j++) {
                    if ( (j % 2) == 0 ) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    int x=0;
                    for (int k = 3; (k*k) <= j; k+=2) {
                        if(j % k == 0) {
                            x=1;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if(x==1) continue;
                    buffer.append(j + " ");
                }
                System.out.println("All the primes b/n number " 
                       + number1  + " and number" + number2 + "  are :" 
                       + buffer.toString() );        
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
              }
        return primes;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Enter two integer numbers to see what "
                           + "is the multitude b/w them: ");
        Number.number();
        }
    }
```

Comment: `if(x==1) continue;
                    buffer.append(j + " ");` in structured programming this is usually written as `if(x/=1) {
                    buffer.append(j + " "); }`. Also, for such flag variables a descriptive name will serve as a self-documentaiton, like `is_composite` instead of `x`. --- +1 for `for (int k = 3; (k*k) <= j; k+=2)`.

Comment: @WillNess Did you mean `if(x!=1)`? `if(x/=1)` will return true if `x` is nonzero.

Comment: @JL2210 thanks; I meant `x` not equals `1`.

Answer (score 0):

My fastest way to check if number is prime:

```
boolean isPrime(int p) {
  int m = (int) Math.sqrt(p);
  if(m<2) {
    return true;
  }else {
    for(int i = 2;i++;i<=m) {
      if((p % i)==0) {
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have given `return` in the `number()` method instead of `break` and `continue`. `number()` method is not called in a loop in the `main()` that you need to return for each iteration. Also the `boolean` return simply doesn't make sense.

I'll show you a few changes you need to do, which will make the program print out a few numbers. But that doesn't mean its the correct output. The logic for prime numbers is highly faulty. You'll have to fix that. I'm just helping you solve the basic problem of why you don't get any output.

```
for (int j = number1; j < number2; j++) {
    if ((j % 2) == 0)
        continue; // return true replaced by continue
    for (int k = 3; (k * k) <= j; k += 2) {
        if (j % k == 0) {
            break; // return false replaced by break
        }
        System.out.println("All the primes b/n number "
                + number1 + " and number" + number2 + "  are :"
                + j);
    }
}
```

I've given the `break` and `continue` to avoid `return` statements, but in reality, the logic really needs a makeover.